# Is it faster to add to a collection then sort it, or add to a sorted collection?

Tags: java, sorting, collections

If I have a `Map` like this:

```
HashMap<Integer, ComparableObject> map;
```

and I want to obtain a collection of values sorted using natural ordering, which method is fastest?

### (A)

Create an instance of a sortable collection like `ArrayList`, add the values, then sort it:

```
List<ComparableObject> sortedCollection = new ArrayList<ComparableObject>(map.values());
Collections.sort(sortedCollection);
```

### (B)

Create an instance of an ordered collection like `TreeSet`, then add the values:

```
Set<ComparableObject> sortedCollection = new TreeSet<ComparableObject>(map.values());
```

Note that the resulting collection is never modified, so the sorting only needs to take place once.

Comment: It depends on the order of input data - eg. if your fetch a lot of rows and use ORDER BY then it's one case - if you have a random set of guids - another.

Comment: Why not use a TreeMap instead?

Comment: TreeMap wouldn't help here because the sorting needs to take place on the values (`ComparableObject`) not the key (`Integer`).

Comment: Also note that a Set only supports unique entries. The "values" Collection of a HashMap on the other hand can contain duplicates. 
From that angle, TreeSet is not a good solution.

Comment: @gutch, you may find my answer at "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3759112/whats-faster-inserting-into-a-priority-queue-or-sorting-retrospectively/10761286#10761286" to be useful.

Comment: how about using an ArrayList and don't use add or remove, but Collections.binarySearch(list, key, comp) before add(index, o) or remove(index). this guarantees O(log n) for add/remove. you benefit from faster iteration but add/remove might be slower because of the array copies.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

TreeSet has a  `log(n)` time complexity guarantuee for `add()/remove()/contains()` methods.
Sorting an `ArrayList` takes `n*log(n)` operations, but `add()/get()` takes only `1` operation.

So if you're mainly retrieving, and don't sort often, `ArrayList` is the better choice. If you sort often but dont retrieve that much `TreeSet` would be a better choice.

Comment: In my case we only need to iterate through the resulting collection, it never gets modified. So based on your answer `ArrayList` is the better choice here.

Comment: Additionally array sorting could be done in parallel and has much better cache performance.

Comment: adding in a sorted ArrayList would itself require sorting, that would take again n logn time, so for adding also, treeset is better.

Comment: @ShubhamAgrawal: 'Better' is a word I would not use here: Both `TreeSet` and a sorted `ArrayList` have the same time complexity for adding elements, as long as you only add elements once, since the sorting can be done in one go after adding the last element: `n*log(n)` As always it depends on the use-case which data structure fits the purpose.

Comment: I agree to @fasseg. I had the same scenario, need to iterate over a sorted list, and benchmarked it: `ArrayList` + `Collections.sort()`, `TreeMap` and `PriorityQueue` (which has also O = N log N). They all reach very similar performance overall, but `PriorityQueue` seems to perform best **in my use case**

Answer (score 26):

Theoretically, sorting at the end should be faster.
Maintaining sorted state through the process could involve additional CPU time.

From the CS points of view, both operations are NlogN, but 1 sort should have lower constant.

Comment: +1 One of those cases where the theory and the reality get disconnected. :)  In my experience, sorting at the end tends to be orders of magnitude faster...

Comment: Unless they're O(N), which would be the case of integer data. Priority queues also involve O(log N) operations for insertion, removal, and management.

Answer (score 10):

Why not use the best of both worlds? If you are never using it again, sort using a TreeSet and initialize an ArrayList with the contents

```
List<ComparableObject> sortedCollection = 
    new ArrayList<ComparableObject>( 
          new TreeSet<ComparableObject>(map.values()));
```

---

EDIT:

I have created a benchmark (you can access it at [pastebin.com/5pyPMJav](http://pastebin.com/5pyPMJav)) to test the three approaches (ArrayList + Collections.sort, TreeSet and my best of both worlds approach) and mine always wins. The test file creates a map with 10000 elements, the values of which have an intentionally awful comparator, and then each of the three strategies get a chance to a) sort the data and b) iterate over it. Here is some sample output (you can test it yourselves):

EDIT: I have added an aspect that logs calls to Thingy.compareTo(Thingy) and I have also added a new Strategy based on PriorityQueues that is much faster than either of the previous solutions (at least in sorting).

```
compareTo() calls:123490
Transformer ArrayListTransformer
    Creation: 255885873 ns (0.255885873 seconds) 
    Iteration: 2582591 ns (0.002582591 seconds) 
    Item count: 10000

compareTo() calls:121665
Transformer TreeSetTransformer
    Creation: 199893004 ns (0.199893004 seconds) 
    Iteration: 4848242 ns (0.004848242 seconds) 
    Item count: 10000

compareTo() calls:121665
Transformer BestOfBothWorldsTransformer
    Creation: 216952504 ns (0.216952504 seconds) 
    Iteration: 1604604 ns (0.001604604 seconds) 
    Item count: 10000

compareTo() calls:18819
Transformer PriorityQueueTransformer
    Creation: 35119198 ns (0.035119198 seconds) 
    Iteration: 2803639 ns (0.002803639 seconds) 
    Item count: 10000
```

Strangely, my approach performs best in iteration (I would have thought there would be no differences to the ArrayList approach in iteration, do I have a bug in my benchmark?)

Disclaimer: I know this is probably an awful benchmark, but it helps get the point across to you and I certainly did not manipulate it to make my approach win.

(The code has a dependency to apache commons / lang for the equals / hashcode / compareTo builders, but it should be easy to refactor it out)

Comment: Wouldn't that actually be the worst of both worlds? All I need is a collection in natural order, which is what `new TreeSet<ComparableObject>(map.values())` returns. Wrapping that in an `ArrayList` is just going to add unnecessary operations.

Comment: The end goal was a sorted `Collection`... which `TreeSet` is.  I see no value is converting the set to a list here.

Comment: it's not wrapping, it's initializing. and and arraylist is better at retrieving while the treeset is better at sorting

Comment: see my comment with the benchmark. you'll be surprised (I was)

Comment: I appeciate the effort you've gone to in writing the benchmark! However I think there is a flaw in it. It appears that the JVM runs `Transformer` instances that are later in the list faster than earlier ones: put `BestOfBothWorldsTransformer` first and it suddenly runs much slower. So I have rewritten your benchmark to randomly select a transformer and average the results. In my test `TreeSetTransformer` consistently beats `BestOfBothWorldsTransformer`, which consistently beats `ArrayListTransformer` — not what I expected at all! The difference is tiny though. See http://pastebin.com/L0t5QDV9

Comment: I know what your next question is: what about PriorityQueueTransformer? Isn't it massively faster than the others? Well yes it is, too bad though that it doesn't get the order correct! Have a look at the lists generated by each transformer in my code above, and you'll see that PriorityQueueTransformer is not actually in order! Maybe I am using `PriorityQueue` incorrectly? Do you have an example of it actually sorting correctly?

Comment: @gutch: yes, I thought the benchmark was flawed. Also, PriorityQueue was an idea I picked up from a comment somewhere, I don't really know the class. Thanks for your efforts, anyway.

Comment: `PriorityQueue` sorts but doesn't allow you to iterate in sorted order. From the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) "The Iterator provided in method iterator() is not guaranteed to traverse the elements of the priority queue in any particular order. If you need ordered traversal, consider using Arrays.sort(pq.toArray())."

Answer (score 7):

Be sure to read my comment about TreeSet at the bottom if you choose to implement B)

If your app only does occasional sorts but iterates through it a lot, I'd say you're best off using a straightforward unsorted list. Sort it the once and then benefit from faster iteration. Iteration is especially fast on an array list.

However if you want sort order to be guaranteed all of the time or you are possibly adding / removing elements frequently then use a sorted collection and take the hit on iteration.

So in your case I would say A) is the better option. The list is sorted once, doesn't change and therefore benefits from being an array. Iteration should be very fast, especially if you *know* its an ArrayList and can directly use the ArrayList.get() instead of an Iterator.

I'd also add that TreeSet by definition is a Set which means objects are unique. A TreeSet determines equality by using compareTo on your Comparator / Comparable. You could easily find yourself missing data if you try to add two objects whose compareTo returns a value of 0. e.g. adding "C", "A", "B", "A" to a TreeSet will return "A", "B", "C"

Comment: Good point about `TreeSet` potentially missing data if compareTo returns 0. I have determined that in this particular case the compareTo implementation will never return 0, so both `TreeSet` and `ArrayList` will behave the same. However I have been caught out by that problem before so thanks for the reminder!

Comment: A PriorityQueue is probably better for sorting a list than a TreeSet.

Comment: yup, in my benchmark (see my answer) PriorityQueue outperforms TreeSet by 600 to 700 %.

Comment: `PriorityQueue` does indeed perform faster, but when I tried it the values were not actually sorted — obviously why it was so fast!
Maybe I misinterpreted how to use PriorityQueue... an example of it actually working would be useful.

Comment: A PriorityQueue is just a queue with a comparator / comparable test. When you add() items to the queue, the insert compares the new item to the ones already there to determine the position to insert at. When you poll() the queue, or iterate it, the contents are already sorted. I expect insertion is done via some kind of recursive algorithm, i.e. split list in two and determine which half to insert it in, split in two again and so on so performance is going to be O(log N) which is theoretically the same as TreeSet / TreeMap, but the implementation may make it faster.

Answer (score 2):

`Collections.sort` uses mergeSort which has O(nlog n).

`TreeSet` has Red-Black tree underlying, basic operations has O(logn). Hence n elements has also O(nlog n).

So both are same big O algorithm.

Comment: Although this sounds true, it covers up some important costs. MergeSort works in O(n log n) time, but Red-Black will require O(n log n) for insertion and again for removal. The big-O notation hides important differences in the algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

Inserting in a SortedSet is O(log(n)) (BUT! the current n and not the final n).
Inserting in a List is 1.

Sorting in a SortedSet is already included in inserting, so it is 0.
Sorting in a List is O(n*log(n)).

So SortedSet total complexity is O(n * k), k < log(n) for all cases but the last.
Instead, List total complexity is O(n * log(n) + n), so O(n * log(n)).

So, SortedSet mathematically has the best performance. But in the end, you have a Set instead of a List (because SortedList doesn't exist) and Set provides you fewer features than List.
So in my opinion, the best solution for available features and performance is the one proposed by Sean Patrick Floyd:

- use a SortedSet for inserting,
- put the SortedSet as a parameter for creating a List to return.

Answer (score 1):

Great question and great answers. Just thought I would add some points to take into account:

1. If your Collection to be sorted is short-lived, for instance, used as an argument to a method, and you need the list sorted within the method, then use Collections.sort(collection). Or if it is long-lived object, but you need to sort it very rarely.

Justification: The sorted collection is required for something specific, and you probably won't add or remove very often. So you don't really care about the elements in the collection once it is sorted. You basically:

sort -> use it -> forget

If you add a new element to the sorted collection, you will have to sort the collection again, as the order is not guaranteed when inserting a new element.

2. If your Collection to be sorted is long-lived and/or if it is a field within a class and you need it to be sorted at **all times** then you should use a sorted data structure such as TreeSet.

Justification: You care about the collection order at all times. You want it to be sorted at all times. So if you constantly add or remove elements you have the guarantee that the collection is sorted. So basically:

insert/remove -> use it (all the time you have the guarantee that the collection is sorted)

There is no specific moment where you need the collection to be sorted, instead, you want the collection to be sorted all the time.

The downside of using TreeSet is the resources it requires to keep the sorted collection. It uses a Red-black tree, and it requires O(log n) time cost for get, put operations.

Whereas if you use a simple collection, such as an ArrayList, the get,add operations are O(1) constant time.