# Getting all leaves of a tree in a sorted order

Tags: java, sorting, data-structures, tree

For a tree structure as follows

```
public class Node implements Comparable<Node> {
    private List<Node> nodes=new ArrayList<Node>();
    private String name="";
    private List<String> leaves=new ArrayList<String>();
    private Node parent=null;

    public List<Node> getNodes() {
        return nodes;
    }

    public void setNodes(List<Node> nodes) {
        this.nodes = nodes;
    }

    public List<String> getLeaves() {
        return leaves;
    }

    public void setLeaves(List<String> leaves) {
        this.leaves = leaves;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Node o) {
        return this.getName().compareTo(o.getName());
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Node getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public void setParent(Node parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public int getDepth() {
        int depth = 0;
        Node parent = this.getParent();
        while (parent != null) {
            depth++;
            parent = parent.getParent();
        }
        return depth;
    }
}
```

From a node, I wish to have a method that returns all the distinct direct and indirect leaves (In the above case the strings `leaves`  would be the leaves), for that node in sorted order.

Above is a **highly** torn down data structure to easy testing and demonstration. I have tried the following 3 approaches,

Approach A 
Very slow when depth is large ~20, since the deepest leaves are traversed to several times, once for each of its ancestor, hence same path is traversed multiple times.

```
    public List<String> getLeavesDeep1() {
        Set<String> leaves = new TreeSet<String>();
        leaves.addAll(getLeaves());
        for (Node node : getNodes()) {
            leaves.addAll(node.getLeavesDeep1());
        }
        return new ArrayList<String>(leaves);
    }
```

Avg: 12694 ms   /   Without sort/distinct> Avg: 471 ms

Approach B
Little faster than A, as the number of nodes  is comparatively very less than leaves, so using the approach A but for nodes, and then for each of the nodes, getting direct leaves only.

```
    private List<Node> getNodesDeep2() {
        Set<Node> nodes = new TreeSet<Node>();
        nodes.addAll(getNodes());
        for (Node node : getNodes()) {
            nodes.addAll(node.getNodesDeep2());
        }
        return new ArrayList<Node>(nodes);
    }

    public List<String> getLeavesDeep2() {
        Set<String> leaves = new TreeSet<String>();
        leaves.addAll(getLeaves());
        for (Node node : getNodesDeep2()) {
            leaves.addAll(node.getLeaves());
        }
        return new ArrayList<String>(leaves);
    }
```

Avg: 4355 ms    /   Without sort/distinct> Avg: 2406 ms

Approach C
Avoid TreeSet, used ArrayList's and sorted & filtered (not the best way to sort/distinct though) just before returning

```
    private List<Node> getNodesDeep3() {
        List<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<Node>();
        nodes.addAll(getNodes());
        for (Node node : getNodes()) {
            nodes.addAll(node.getNodesDeep3());
        }
        return new ArrayList<Node>(new TreeSet<Node>(nodes));
    }

    public List<String> getLeavesDeep3() {
        List<String> leaves = new ArrayList<String>();
        leaves.addAll(getLeaves());
        for (Node node : getNodesDeep3()) {
            leaves.addAll(node.getLeaves());
        }
        return new ArrayList<String>(new TreeSet<String>(leaves));
    }
```

Avg: 4400

Looking for something faster, I know there are certain tree traversals that can be used, but I would prefer something simpler if there exists. *P.S. These is no use case for searching at the moment*. In my real class the times are much higher approx 3x to the above cases, as the structure is much more complex with the leaves not being simple strings, but POJOs

Following is the test I have used to get the times

```
private static final int NODES = 5;
private static final int LEAVES = 25;
private static final int DEPTH = 8;

public void addChildren(Node parent) {
    List<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<Node>();
    List<String> leaves = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < LEAVES; i++) {
        leaves.add(String.format("%s_leaf_%s", parent.getName(), i));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < NODES; i++) {
        Node child = new Node();
        child.setParent(parent);
        child.setName(String.format("%s_%s", parent.getName(), i));
        nodes.add(child);
        if (child.getDepth() < DEPTH) {
            addChildren(child);
        }
    }
    parent.setNodes(nodes);
    parent.setLeaves(leaves);
}

@Test
public void testCase() {
    long start, tot=0;
    long t = 0;
    List<String> leaves;
    Node target = new Node();
    target.setName("Root");
    addChildren(target);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        leaves = target.getLeavesDeep5();
        t = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
        tot += t;
        System.out.println(leaves.size() + " " + t);
    }

    System.out.println("Avg: " + (tot / 10));
}
```

Answers in any language are acceptable including pseudo code, as long as it doesn't tightly tie the solution to that language (*Exception: Pure java code is barred from the second clause*)

Comment: Is this test intended for us or you?

Comment: @HotLicks, I thought I would include it here, in case any one has a better approach and want to give it a try before posting the solution. Gives a better picture as to how is being tested for speed.

Comment: May your tree be a binary search tree? Is so, you will just need to traverse it in in-order traversal.

Comment: @davidbuzatto It isn't binary, there are no fixed number of children, roughly 5 nodes, on average and ~20 leaves per node.

Comment: Can nodes that have children also have "leaves"?

Comment: @RealzSlaw yes, thats what I am trying to signify by using `Node` for non leaf nodes and `String` for leaf nodes. Each non leaf node on avg has ~4-5 nodes as children and ~15-20 leaf nodes as children. Assumption is depth will be less than 8 levels

Comment: I am very very confused; you are using "leaves/leaf" interchangeably. Instead perhaps use "values" and "leafs"? Or am I still misunderstanding.

Comment: correct (`string`)values are leaves. Please refer the very first piece of code that defines the class structure, here a `Node` object will have a `List<Node> nodes` property and another `List<String> leaves` property, the 1st being the non-leaf children and the latter the leaf children for the given (`this`) `node` object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran your test and it gave me the following results (i used your version 3, one slightly modified version3 and a new version)

```
2441400 8038
...
2441400 7890
Avg: 7872

2441400 4850
...
2441400 3990
Avg: 4165

2441400 980
...
2441400 710
Avg: 786
```

I first changed

```
return new ArrayList<String>(new TreeSet<String>(leaves));
```

to

```
Collections.sort(leaves);
return leaves;
```

See [Is it faster to add to a collection then sort it, or add to a sorted collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3607593/is-it-faster-to-add-to-a-collection-then-sort-it-or-add-to-a-sorted-collection)

Which gave an almost 50% reduction in execution time. 
Note: **The TreeSet will remove duplicates, sort will not.**

I then wrote a new Iterator method combining your 2 methods into one and eliminating recursion all together. I also got rid of ArrayLists to avoid the resizing and copying which we don't need because we only iterate and never access by index.

**Edit**: using ArrayList to store the leaves increases time from 800ms to about 1400ms.

```
public List<String> getLeavesDeepX()
{
    final Deque<Node> nodes = new LinkedList<Node>();
    final Collection<String> leaves = new LinkedList<String>();
    //final Collection<String> leaves = new LinkedHashSet<String>(); -- use for removing dupes
    nodes.add(this);
    do
    {
        final Node current = nodes.pop();
        leaves.addAll(current.getLeaves());
        nodes.addAll(current.getTreeNodes());
    }
    while(nodes.isEmpty() == false);

    final ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>(leaves);
    Collections.sort(result);
    return result;
}
```

I put all results into different lists and compared those at the end.

```
    System.out.println(Arrays.equals(leaves1.toArray(), leaves2.toArray()));
    System.out.println(Arrays.equals(leaves1.toArray(), leaves3.toArray()));
    System.out.println(Arrays.equals(leaves2.toArray(), leaves3.toArray()));
```

Output:

```
true
true
true
```

So at least on my system its about a 10 fold increase in speed.

**Edit2**: Skipping the sorting in case 3 brings it to 140ms. So 600ms are used comparing and sorting. Any further major improvement needs to be done there.

**Edit3**: Eliminating recursion also has the benefit that the depth of the tree has less impact on performance. Changing the TestTree to 2/2/20 (N/L/D) yields about the same number of leaves(2m) but performs much worse with recursion (>70k) but is not much slower (2500 from 1200) without.

Comment: Hey cool finally an answer, looks promising too. Let me give a try when i get my hands on a machine. I haven't tried your solution yet, but i read in your answer about duplicates. I do want to remove duplicates as i need distinct leaves

Comment: @JugalThakkar you can replace one line in the method. Instead of a LinkedList for storing the leaves use a LinkedHashSet. For some reason HashSet is actually slower in this case. TreeSet should be avoided unless you need the sorting to be available over a period where you add elements. Otherwise its always slower than new ArrayList + sort. However if memory is a constraint adding new possibly huge temporary lists may not be an option.

Comment: Also using a LinkedHashSet to remove dupes will increase the runtime (for me it was about 50% from 800 to 1200). Using a TreeSet to reduce peak memory consumption (and avoid GC) increases it again. (1200 to 2500 for me)

Comment: Well after giving some thoughts I realized, I won't be getting duplicates and hence can avoid the set, only my very first approach (the worst) resulted in duplicates as same branch was traversed multiple times. Full marks for helping me avoid recursion, I had tough time figuring that out, but now its clear, a stack always comes to the rescue. Thanks for such a beautiful and detailed answer !!