# Using a stack as a Queue in Java

Tags: java, stack, queue

I need to process a tree in different orders, let's say BFS and DFS. Both is easy by using a queue or a stack, however, I'm missing a proper interface in Java allowing to do something like

```
QueueOrStack<N> pending = ...
while (!pending.isEmpty()) {
    N node = pending.poll(); // <----- this is the problem
    pending.addAll(node.children());
    process(node);
}
```

There's no real problem, I can encapsulate an `ArrayList` into something implementing `Queue`<sup>1</sup>, however I'd bet I'm overlooking something in the Java Collection Framework. Or is it really missing?

__

<sup>1</sup> or use a newest-first comparator with a `PriorityQueue`, which is probably a dumb idea

Answer (score 5):

There is such a structure.

It is called `ArrayDeque` -> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html

Comment: +1 - I've never used the class, but I glanced at the doc and it looks exactly like what is needed for this case. It is also worth pointing out that the doc states "This class is likely to be faster than Stack when used as a stack, and faster than LinkedList when used as a queue." which is nice!

Comment: Indeed, the structure is [`Deque`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) and the `ArrayDeque` is an implementation.

Comment: @Alexander Pogrebnyak: I see it has all the needed operations, but I still need to do something like `N node = asStack ? pending.pollLast() : pending.pollFirst()`. But this is not bad.

Comment: @maaartinus: Make your own class with an ArrayDeque as a field, and a boolean asStack. Then expose the methods you want (i.e. `public E poll() { asStack ? pending.pollLast() : pending.pollFirst() }`). You can make it implement the Stack<E> and Queue<E> interfaces if you like.

Comment: @maaartinus LinkedList also implements Deque and atleast [in this case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12393116/getting-all-leaves-of-a-tree-in-a-sorted-order/12785711#12785711) it performs better than an array based one.