# What's the worst-case time complexity of TreeSet?

Tags: java, hashmap, time-complexity

It is stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3607593/is-it-faster-to-add-to-a-collection-then-sort-it-or-add-to-a-sorted-collection) that

> TreeSet has a log(n) time complexity guarantuee for add()/remove()/contains().

But `TreeSet` uses a binary search tree and in the worst case, binary search trees can have O(n) height. How is the log(n) complexity "guaranteed"?

Comment: What do you mean "if tree is skewed"?

Comment: It's based on a red-black tree, so it self-balances.

Answer (score 3):

The implementation rebalances the tree upon inserts.

The O(lg n) time bound for `insert` is guaranteed by the [official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html). This should not come as a surprise: A classic way to implement sets is as  some sort of [self-balancing binary search tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree#Applications).

Java libraries are publicly available, so let's go see for ourselves. `TreeSet` can be    found, e.g., [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/util/TreeSet.java). It is implemented in terms of `TreeMap`,  which is in turn [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/util/TreeMap.java). As @Don Roby points out, the underlying data structure is a Red-Black tree.

Comment: +1:  I believe indeed it is done using a red-black tree.